How can CSS transform maintain the same angle on different element widths?
I created a pretty nice tabs interface with plain HTML and SCSS,
jsfiddle and code below.

When integrated with my Angular UI, it does everything I need - active tab and different colors. But now I see that the transform causes the angle of the edges and overlap to change depending on the length of the text. Also, the span inside which I use to offset that transformation is skewing the text in the other direction. Is there a way to keep the edge angles and overlap the same and the text straight, no matter the length? (I suspect that CSS trigonometric functions are going to be necessary here.)
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li class="active positions-tab"><span>Tab 1</span></li>
    <li class="positions-tab"><span>Tab 2</span></li>
    <li class="positions-tab"><span>Very loooooong Tab</span></li>
    <li class="reports-tab"><span>X</span></li>
    <li class="reports-tab"><span>Tab 3</span></li>
    <li class="stock-tab"><span>Tab 4</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

$positions-tab-color: #f2a870;
$reports-tab-color: #70BFEE;
$stock-tab-color: #66D572;
@mixin tabcolor($color) {
    background: $color;
    border: 1px solid darken($color, 20);
    border-bottom: none;
    color: darken($color, 40);
    &.active {
        box-shadow: 1px 0px 5px darken($color, 40);
    }
}
div.tabs {
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 2px;
    ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding:0;
        li {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: 0 -5px 0 0;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            border-top-left-radius: 5px;
            border-top-right-radius: 5px;
            transform: perspective(4px) rotateX(2deg);
            transform-origin: bottom;
            filter: saturate(15%) brightness(130%);
            @include tabcolor(#aaa);
            &.stock-tab {
                @include tabcolor($stock-tab-color);
            }
            &.positions-tab {
                @include tabcolor($positions-tab-color);
            }
            &.reports-tab {
                @include tabcolor($reports-tab-color);
            }
            &:hover {
                filter: saturate(30%) brightness(120%);
                transition: all 0.1s ease;
                color: #333;
                cursor: pointer;
                &.active {
                    border-color: #000;
                }
            }
            &.active {
                filter: saturate(100%) brightness(100%);
                z-index: 2;
                color: #000;
            }
            span {
                // text of tab (undo transform)
                transform: perspective(4px) rotateX(-2deg);
                display: block;
                user-select: none;
                text-decoration: none;
                font: bold 11pt Helvetica;
            }
        }
    }
}




AFAIK not really. Another methodology would be ideal. A clip-path perhaps?

I would suggest constructing the tab shape using pseudo-elements instead, which will make it easier to keep the angles consistent regardless of the width of the tab.
This approach uses two skewed pseudo-elements—one before and one after the tab's contents—to create the trapezoidal shape of the tab. The border is selectively applied to the appropriate sides of the pseudo-elements, as well as the top of the contents. It lines up so that it seems like a continuous border around the tab.


.tablist {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1rem;
}
.tab {
  --angle: 20deg;
  --offset: 0.5ch;
  --border-color: black;
  --border-radius: 5px;
  --border-width: 1px;
  --background-color: powderblue;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 1.6ch;
}
.tab::before,
.tab::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 2ch;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: var(--background-color);
  border-top: var(--border-width) solid var(--border-color);
}
.tab::before {
  left: calc(-1 * var(--offset));
  transform: skewX(calc(-1 * var(--angle)));
  transform-origin: top right;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius) 0 0 0;
  border-left: var(--border-width) solid var(--border-color);
}
.tab::after {
  right: calc(-1 * var(--offset));
  transform: skewX(var(--angle));
  transform-origin: top left;
  border-radius: 0 var(--border-radius) 0 0;
  border-right: var(--border-width) solid var(--border-color);
}
.tab-contents {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: var(--offset) 0;
  background: var(--background-color);
  border-top: var(--border-width) solid var(--border-color);
  z-index: 1;
}
<ol class="tablist">
  <li><button class="tab" type="button"><span class="tab-contents">lorem</span></button></li>
  <li><button class="tab" type="button"><span class="tab-contents">ipsum dolor amit</span></button></li>
  <li><button class="tab" type="button"><span class="tab-contents">consecutor</span></button></li>
</ol>



